# How to include image to twig using Openlayers 3 script in symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony, anchor, openlayers-3, src

How to include image to twig using Openlayers 3 script in symfony 2.8 ?

Nor asset, nor referencing from root, nor referencing from the current directory does not work.

```
      src: "{{ asset('bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg')  }}"  // does not work
      src: "{{ asset('/bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg')  }}"  // does not work
       src: "/bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg"  // from root directory also does no work
       src: "../../../images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg"  // referencing from the current directory also does no work
```

Code is from the example :
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/drag-features.html

I just have used different map, which works and is displayed, used only one feature - point with different coordinates, which does not work, it is not displayed on the map.

//twig template

```
<script>

  window.onload = function() {
  var lat = document.getElementById('edit_form.latitude').value; 
  var lon = document.getElementById('edit_form.longitude').value; 

var pointM = [ parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat) ];
var pointMWebMercator = ol.proj.fromLonLat( pointM, 'EPSG:3857' );
console.log( ' pointMWebMercator m= '+ pointMWebMercator);

var pointFeature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(pointMWebMercator));


var map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new app.Drag()]),
  target: 'Openmap',  // The DOM element that will contains the map
  renderer: 'canvas', // Force the renderer to be used
  size: [200, 200],
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({  source: new ol.source.OSM()  }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [pointFeature]
      }),
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
            // @type {olx.style.IconOptions} 
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          opacity: 0.95,
          src: "{{ asset('bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg')  }}"  // does not work
         // src: "{{ asset('/bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg')  }}"  // does not work
         //  src: "/bundles/meeting/images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg"  // from root directory also does no work
         //  src: "../../../images/google-map-pointer-grey.svg"  // referencing from the current directory also does no work

}) ),

  //  A leading slash tells the browser to start at the root directory.
//// i can get the root directory from//print_r("SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
//// for symfony it is project/web
  //  If you don't have the leading slash, you're referencing from the current directory.
 //   If you add two dots before the leading slash, it means you're referencing the parent of the current directory.



        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 3,
          color: [255, 0, 0, 1]
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: [0, 0, 255, 0.6]
        })
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: pointMWebMercator,
    zoom: 14
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig has nothing to do with embedding `openlayers`. As it's a javascript library.

Twig executes and generates `HTML` in server side. `OpenLayer` script is supposed to be executed in client side.

Also, The [openlayers document](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I can include image if i use simple own script ( and own simple MVC).  I mean i understand how to implement src in OpenLayers, but in Symfony this does not work . How to make this in Symfony 2.8?

Comment: I also can include the image in the body of Symfony project view twig template  which owns OpenLayer 3 javascript. But i am not able to assign image to src in script itself.

Comment: I mean i can include image to OpenLayer 3 if i make it in php script, or own simple MVC. Nevertheless, i can not make this in Symfony 2 project.  But i can inlude image in any Symfony 2 project template, nevertheless not in the OpenLayer 3 script in the template. I tried to include the image in the same template which contains OpenLayer script. Image is included to the template using any of three ways described. But if i try to inlcude it to script with OpenLayer object - it does not work.

Comment: Give me tim to double check everyhting once more - will write back in 8 hours